# Ubuntu is not painting / rendering the windows properly

Tags: 14.04, unity, window

I am running ubuntu 14.04 OS on a system76 serval laptop. I have the Nvidia driver installed, but it seams that sometimes some popup windows are not rendered properly in phpstorm. Any ideas how to fix this? Do I need to install a special driver?

[image]

Comment: Hi Paul.

What application do you have running there? Does this ever happen in any other applications?

I looked up your order (I work for System76), and it looks like you have a SerW8. Can you confirm for me how you installed the Nvidia driver? I'd need to know if you're using the pre-installed copy or if you reinstalled something different and how.

Comment: Thanks for answering Ian.  I was hoping that I would be able to capitalize on getting a super configured and professionally installed linux machine from you guys - but your technitions opted to install the OS on the slowest drive in my unit instead of the super fast drive (PCIE) that came with it... so after receiving it, I had to re-install the OS... which sucked cuz I was hoping your experts could have done that step for me - unfortunately, I dont remember which nvidia driver was installed... i was hoping u guys would have done that for me - what nvidia do I need?

Comment: P.S. This app is PHPStorm by Jetbrains

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your running Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK or integrated-JDK (the one PHPstorm comes up with).

You can follow this guide about how to fix font anti-aliasing, but it could help with your Orace JDK settings.

https://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi